# AFrame Project run no script in GearVR Samsung Internet

Tags: javascript, aframe, gear-vr

I am writing a AFrame prject. It works good in 2D browser like chrome on my laptop.

But the the scripts don't run in Samsung Internet in Gear VR.

Maybe have someone ideal about it?

Demo: http://webvr.virtualskillslab.de

Github: https://github.com/LeMueller/skills-lab-web (in develop branch)

Comment: You’re pointing to a very large project that is hard to disect. If you can come up with a simple A-Frame example that reproduces the problem it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run it in Samsung Internet for VR, I get

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

on the last line of this fragment:

```js
function putOnTable(){
    console.log("put on table: ");
    Object(_utils_aAnimationWrapper__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"])(
        element, '', 'position', schema.inCan, schema.outOfCan, schema.dur,
        '', true, 'forwards',
    );
```

So

1. Lint your code, or use your IDE's syntax checker
2. Post a version that isn't minified (or at least has sourcemaps) when asking for help
3. Use Chrome's Remote Debugging to view the JavaScript console log: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/vrweb/latest/concepts/carmel-remote-debugging/

Comment: You are right, the comma before closing parenthesis must be removed. Thank you very much for you realy helpful advises about debugging.